# Is there a siddur for the Jews of Aden?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, prayer-book, yemenite-temani

Do Adenim (Jews from the Yemenite city of Aden) have a nusach and a siddur unique to them?

Comment: Do you have any sources that suggest it differs from other Yemenite rites?

Comment: Most likely it would follow either the nusach of the Jews of Teiman or Amram Gaon or Saadia Gaon. But it is possible that the Lemba, in east-central Africa have some distinct tradition. They are supposed to be descendants of the Jewish community in Aden.

Comment: Among the Lemba, the Buba clan have their most accurate tradition. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemba_people

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sana%27a

Comment: I would assume they would use a Teimani siddur of some kind, maybe Baladi?

Comment: AFAIK, Aden doesn’t have a unique *siddur*, at most it depended if the Adeni was Bal’adi (townsman) or Shami (city-folk). Yet, both used a Tichlal with (minor?) differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a Siddur that fits the bill! It is called Siddur Sim Shalom and is Nusach Aden. It can be found here:
https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=196528&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0

Comment: Ironically, "Siddur Sim Shalom" is also the title of the popular Conservative siddur.

Comment: Did you read the publisher’s preface?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the Adeni nusach is probably most similar to Shamai. In some Adeni shuls they use books similar to the [Zechor LeAvraham siddur](http://www.nosachteiman.co.il/?CategoryID=580&ArticleID=532) (Shamai), but many now use their own [Sim Shalom siddur](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=196528) (Adeni). To be honest, a lot of Adenim just use Edot HaMizrah siddurim because that's what they're used to.

There was an Adeni siddur published a little before Sim Shalom, but the contents are very similar.

A lot of the Adeni prayers do differ to both Shamai and Baladi. Some of the differences seem to be unique to Aden, others have been taken from Sephardi or Ashkenazi liturgy. Even within Adeni shuls there are differences in the prayer. As a point of history, the Jews of Aden (and in fact many communities) got their siddurim from Livorno and would just make do with any differences in the liturgy.

Comment: Joshua, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for this informative answer! I hope you'll look around for other questions to answer or information that interests you, perhaps in our [tag:yemenite-temani] or [tag:prayer-book] tags. I look forward to seeing your around!